# How do slow down a matlab script so that you can view graphs updating

Tags: matlab

Is there a way in matlab to slow down the execution time of a script so that you can view the graphs? I currently use breakpoints and step through the code but that is not ideal for showing demos.

Comment: Is `pause` what you want? Try this example: `for k = 1:10, plot(rand(1,100)), pause(1), end`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the pause function

```
pause(1)
```

In this way matlab should sleep for 1 second and you can see your graphic construction

https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/55874-how-to-stop-delay-execution-for-specified-time